# Visual Studio Debugger continuously plays the standard warning sound

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a very strange issue/problem:

When debugging my application (a humongous c++ software making many strange things), the Visual Studio Debugger keeps playing the Windows default warning beep sound, over and over. Mostly on interaction within my 3D renderer.

If I start the application outside Visual Studio, no sounds.

If I start the application within Visual Studio without debugger, no sounds.

If I start the application with the Debugger, Bing Bing Bing Bing Bing...

If I start the application outside Visual Studio and attach with the Debugger to process, Bing Bing Bing Bing Bing...

I checked with the sound applet in the control panel, it really is "Standard Warning" sound.

By the way, there are no runtime errors logged by the Debugger. The application runs just fine as far as I can tell.

Oh, and I am talking about Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10, and C++.

Any Ideas how I can get rid of these sound bings? Anyone had this issue before? It is definitly a first for me... *sigh*

Comment: Whether all apps have the same issue or just the specific one? Do you debug it in other VS machine? Sorry for that I didn't meet this issue before, but I think we have to make sure that whether it is related to the Windows Environment or the specific project itself, in addition, do you get any warning or error messages or a pop window in your side during debugging time?

Comment: Is there some code buried deep in your humungous application that detects a debugger is attached and plays the default sound?  Some sort of poor-mans DRM?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have any sound assigned to 'Debugger hit' in the Sounds?

Comment: This is all very strange. No, i did not set a sound for 'Debugger hit'. No, our software does not play any sounds or suppresses messageboxes or does any bad DRM stuff (as far as I know). I debug locally on my machine. And now it gets strange: it is persistent for only exactly one project on exactly my machine. Identical project copied to a co-workers machine does work fine. Any other project on my machine works fine. Oh well. I assume it is just one bad mix of Karma. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Knowleech, If just the specific app has this issue, it would be not the VS debugger tool issue, we would think about the project itself or the windows Environment. How about creating a new blank solution? You could add this project to this blank solution, and then re-compile and debug it again.